# how to stop this div's from overlapping?

Tags: html, css

So I have 3 divs side by side inside the div element and another div after them. However, this div is overlapping the others. How can I make "footer" come after "main"?

```css
.main {
  height: 500px;
  width: 100%;
  position: absolute;
}

.filter {
  background: red;
  height: 100%;
  float: left;
  width: 20%;
}

.post-bar {
  background: blue;
  height: 100%;
  float: left;
  width: 60%;
}

.advertisment {
  background: green;
  height: 100%;
  float: left;
  width: 20%;
}

.footer {
  height: 250px;
  width: 100%;
  background: black;
  position: relative;
}
```

```html
<div class="main">
  <div class="filter">

  </div>
  <div class="post-bar">

  </div>
  <div class="advertisment">
  </div>

</div>
<div class="footer"></div>
```

Comment: Not using absolute positioning would be a good start. https://philipwalton.github.io/solved-by-flexbox/demos/holy-grail/

Comment: We have `<main>`, `<footer>` and `<aside>` now. No need to use `<div>` for everything.

Comment: Don't use `position:absolute`. Remove this from your `.main` div and all is good.

Comment: it doesn't work on chrome, can you help me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just get rid off `position:absolute` in your main class:

```css
.main {
  height: 500px;
  width: 100%;
}

.filter {
  background: red;
  height: 100%;
  float: left;
  width: 20%;
}

.post-bar {
  background: blue;
  height: 100%;
  float: left;
  width: 60%;
}

.advertisment {
  background: green;
  height: 100%;
  float: left;
  width: 20%;
}

.footer {
  height: 250px;
  width: 100%;
  background: black;
  position: relative;
}
```

```html
<div class="main">
  <div class="filter">

  </div>
  <div class="post-bar">

  </div>
  <div class="advertisment">
  </div>

</div>
<div class="footer"></div>
```

Comment: Yes it works in the snippet, but for some reason, it doesn't want to work in chrome.

Comment: check if there are no other overwriting classes, or try reseting cache by pressing ctrl + f5

Answer (score 1):

Just remove the

> ```
> position: absolute;
> display: block;
> ```

from 
`.main`

I think you will find your desired result. Please , inform if there are any other issues. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Remove positions from main and footer.

```
.main {
  height: 500px;
  width: 100%;
  float:left;
}

.footer {
  height: 250px;
  width: 100%;
  background: black;
  float:left;
}
```